# sending message over SIP

Tags: image, message, sip, voip

I can send SIP messages in plain/text format and my SIP server (voipswitch) is accepting it. To same server when I send SIP messages as image. I'm getting NOT ACCEPTABLE HERE. Should my server need to support MSRTP for accepting images over SIP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIP works with an [offer/answer model](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264), in which the offer and answer seek to establish a set of common media capabilities. A `488 Not Acceptable Here` indicates that there is no set of common media capabilities.

So yes, your SIP server must support [MSRP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4975) if you wish to use MSRP in your session.